# Minimum Separating Distance Between Two Ellipsoids

Tags: optimization, conic-sections

Suppose I have two ellipsoids in three dimensions, defined by:

$Q_{0} = (X-v_{0})^{T}A_{0}(X-v_{0})-1 = 0$

$Q_{1} = (X-v_{1})^{T}A_{1}(X-v_{1})-1 = 0$

Is there a technique to find the minimum distance and direction that $v_{0}$ must be displaced from $v_{1}$ such that the ellipsoids are not overlapping?

Comment: Presumably, your ellipsoids are defined by $Q_0 = 0$ and $Q_1 = 0$.

Comment: Good point, edited them in

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact distance, but a possibly useful lower bound would be the sum of the lengths of the minor axes, namely
$$
d = \frac{1}{\lambda_{\max}(A_0)} + \frac{1}{\lambda_{\max}(A_1)}.
$$

Comment: Adding to @Omnomnomnom comment, you can have an upper bound as,
$$\
d = \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A_0)} + \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A_1)}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial answer:**

Without loss of generality, take $v_0 = 0$. Consider the minimization problem
$$
\min X^TA_0 X \quad \text{s.t.} \quad (X - v_1)^TA_1 (X-v_1) = 1.
$$
The two ellipsoids overlap if this minimum is $1$ or smaller. Our goal is ultimately to find the $v$ of smallest magnitude for which this minimum is exactly $1$. With Lagrange multipliers, we end up with the equation
$$
2A_0X = \lambda(2 A_1X - A_1v_1) \implies
2(\lambda A_1 - A_0)X = A_1 v_1 \implies\\
2(\lambda I - A_1^{-1}A_0)X = v_1.
$$

Comment: Thanks very much! I know nothing about Lagrange multipliers, but I understand I can solve it with Python. I have no idea how to write this though - I will have a look.

Comment: Should X in this case be a given point on the surface of Q0?

Comment: @Jack $X$ in the minimization problem I give is a point on the surface of $Q_1$, not $Q_0$

Answer (score 0):

The closed-form formula exists for two ellipses(2D). It's pretty long. You can find it [here](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistanceEllipse2Ellipse2.pdf). I am not sure if there exists a closed-form formula for two Ellipsoids but for the iterative solution you can use [this](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/franz.vesely/notes/hard_ellipse/hell_jsm.html).